# Can't compare the input I take from simple socket server

Tags: c, sockets, server

I just want to take user input such as GET_DATE and show the date. But when I check if the client wrote GET_DATE by using strcmp it doesn't seem to work. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
 char date_message[] = "GET_DATE";
    //Receive a message from client
    while ((read_size = recv(client_sock, client_message, 2000, 0)) > 0)
    {
        if (strcmp(client_message, date_message) == 0)
        {

            printf("it works");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("it doesn't work");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If TCP, then fatally flawed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The user input contains also `\r\n`.

You can change `char date_message[] = "GET_DATE"` to `char date_message[] = "GET_DATE\r\n"` or parse the input and then compare it as you did.

Comment: After I changed char date_message[] = "GET_DATE\r\n" it worked. But same problem occured again I undo the changes I have done but I'm having the same problem again. Do you have a solution ? Thanks.

Comment: @babayaga you're probably reading another character that you can't see, use the debugger to see the value of `read_size`